# Upgrade to ubuntu 16.04 from Dell Inspiron 15-3552

Tags: 14.04, upgrade, dell

i bought a Dell laptop preinstalled with ubuntu TS 14.04
I could not upgrade it properly to LTS 16.04

I even tried to install ubuntu from a DVD,I had used on my previous laptop,as upgrades from there were easy  . This did not work either,as the DVD did not open.

it had to do with linux headers 4.13.4 which do not work properly, i could open the LTS using the bios and starting generic 3.15.7 (those were the numbers I recall.

Solutions?
Ideas?

Could the pre installed default programme by DELL be the reason for those problems?

Answer (score 0):

Dell Inspiron 15 3552 has not got an ubuntu certificate for 16.04 and 18.04. However, for 14.04 it works well. A clean install with 14.04 solves your problems.